# Fibonacci numbers with GMP lib

Tags: c, gmp

EDIT: solved. ans var needed to be set to 0 in every iteration.That was a mistake I overlooked.A mpz_set_ui(ans,0); at the beginning of each loop solves the problem.Thanks to Oli Charlesworth for his effort!

I'm coding a fibonacci function in C using the GMP library,I use the matrix multiplication algorithm,but for some unexpected reason,I get wrong results(I strongly believe that the algorithm is right).It must have something to do with Gmp structs and inits.Any ideas?

```
/*********************************************************
Find n th Fibonacci number.Matrix algorithm.
+--          --+     +--     --+
|f(n+1) f(n)   |     | 1     1 |  ^n
|              |  == |         |
|f(n)   f(n-1) |     | 1     0 |
+--          --+     +--     --+
*********************************************************/

int
fastfib(mpz_t result,int n)
{


    int cons[2][2]={{1,1},{1,0}};      //"constant" matrix
    mpz_t mat[2][2];                   //actual matrix holding fibonacci numbers
    mpz_t ans;                         //holds f(n+1)   
    mpz_t return_val;                  //used for calculations
    mpz_t temp;                        //used for calculations as well

    //initialize (automatically set to zero)
    mpz_init(ans);
    mpz_init(return_val);
    mpz_init(temp);
    mpz_init(mat[0][0]);
    mpz_init(mat[0][1]);
    mpz_init(mat[1][0]);
    mpz_init(mat[1][1]);

    //start with n=1
    mpz_set_ui(mat[0][0],1);
    mpz_set_ui(mat[1][0],1);
    mpz_set_ui(mat[0][1],1);
    mpz_set_ui(mat[1][1],0);

    //some trivial cases
    if(n==0){
        mpz_set_ui(result,0);
        return 0;
    }
    if(n==1){
        mpz_set_ui(result,1);
        return 0;
    }
    if(n==2){
        mpz_set_ui(result,1);
        return 0;
    }

    n--;


    while(n>1){

        //fib[n+1]
        //ans=mat[0][0]*cons[0][0]+mat[0][1]*cons[1][0];

        mpz_set_ui(ans,0);

        mpz_mul_ui(temp,mat[0][0],cons[0][0]);
        mpz_add(ans,ans,temp);
        mpz_mul_ui(temp,mat[0][1],cons[1][0]);
        mpz_add(ans,ans,temp);

        //update matrix


        mpz_set(mat[1][1],mat[1][0]);   //mat[1][1]=mat[1][0];
        mpz_set(mat[1][0],mat[0][0]);   //mat[0][1]=mat[1][0]=mat[0][0];
        mpz_set(mat[0][1],mat[0][0]);
        mpz_set(mat[0][0],ans);         //mat[0][0]=ans;

        n--;
    }


    //clear vars
    mpz_clear(ans);
    mpz_clear(return_val);
    mpz_clear(temp);

    mpz_set(result,mat[0][0]);
    return 0;

}
```

Some debug info

```
results for n=2       // expected
2 1                   //  2 1
1 1                   //  1 1

results for n=3
5 2                   //  3 2
2 1                   //  2 1

results for n=4
12 5                  //  5 3
5 2                   //  3 2

results for n=5
29 12                 //  8 5
12 5                  //  5 3

results for n=6
70 29                 //  13 8
29 12                 //  8  5

70
```

Comment: Well, at what point does it go wrong?  After the first iteration?  What are the results you get?

Comment: I can't break and debug with the gmp structs...I don't know how to get their values.I can only get the final result with a gmp_print.For instance fib 30 gives 44560482149 which certainly is not the case.

Comment: Why can't you just print out the matrix on every iteration of your while loop?

Comment: results for n=2
2 1
1 1
results for n=3
5 2
2 1
results for n=4
12 5
5 2
results for n=5
29 12
12 5
results for n=6
70 29
29 12

 where I print the first row and then the second

Comment: That's kind of hard to read.  Can you update your answer to include this information, so it can be formatted.  Also, you should include a comparison against what the *expected* output should be, so people don't have to figure it out themselves.

Comment: Well sorry about that,I'm not very familiar with editing on stack.I noticed that for n=5 I should have got f(5)=5 and I got a 29.Normally,the leftmost elements of the previous array should add up to make the next fib number.For some reason this fails.

Comment: There should be an edit button near the bottom of the question but above these comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help!I'll try to make this algorithm faster with [fast exponentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: Your results indicate that you are getting `2*mat[0][0]+mat[0][1]` instead of `mat[0][0] + mat[0][1]`. Can you double check that `ans` is indeed zero before the first `mpz_add(ans, ans, temp)`, and also that `const[0][0]` is 1 instead of 2? The code looks OK, so it's best to ensure reality still holds. :)

Comment: If this is solved, please write your solution as an answer to this question. After some time, you can accept it. That will mark this question as resolved, so it will no longer appear under "Unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. ans var needed to be set to 0 in every iteration.That was a mistake I overlooked.A mpz_set_ui(ans,0); at the beginning of each loop solves the problem.Thanks to Oli Charlesworth for his effort!